# Pass mixed value Json list to MVC Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this Json:

```
{
    'TypeName': 'MyType',
    'Values':
    {
        value1: 12,
        value2: 'asdf',
        value3: 32.2
    }
}
```

The values can be either strings or numbers, and the amount of values is not set (so it could be 3, but also 5 or 12). I have a method in MVC:

```
class CoolObject{
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public ?????? Values { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoStuff(CoolObject values){
    //Do cool stuff with cool object
}
```

What type of object should CoolObject include for this to work??

Comment: Why not use a Newtonsoft.Json.Linq and Parse the text into a dynamic object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON is not a valid JSON, it should look more like this:

```
{
    "TypeName": "MyType",
    "Values": {
        "value1": 12,
        "value2": "asdf",
        "value3": 32.2
    }
}
```

Or you can have array there. But let's assume it is like this one. Then you can try this classes to work with that:

```
class CoolObjectValues
{
  public object value1 { get; set; }
  public object value2 { get; set; }
  public object value3 { get; set; }
}

class CoolObject
{
  public string TypeName { get; set; }
  public CoolObjectValues Values { get; set; }
}
```

Note that when you want to work with values inside CoolObjectValues, you would want to determine what the values type is. For that you can do something like this:

```
int intValue;
if (int.TryParse(co.Values.value1.ToString(), out intValue))
{
  // it was int and you now have its value in intValue
}
else 
{
  // it was string
}
```

**Update:**

For uncertain number of values:

```
{
    "TypeName": "MyType", 
    "Values": {
        "value1": 12,
        "value2": "asdf",
        "value3": 32.2,
        ...
    }
}
```

Your classes will look like this:

```
class CoolObject
{
  public string TypeName { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, object> Values { get; set; }
}
```

and you can work with it like this:

```
  CoolObject co = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CoolObject>(jsonData);
  foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp in co.Values)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
```

Comment: Was just typing this. Do a tryparse for number type first then consider it a string.

Comment: My mistake, I fixed the syntax of my Json. I also slightly elaborated the question: the amount of values is not set. So putting objects in CoolObject would not work like that. :-)

Comment: Thanks! I'm on my way home right now, but I'm trying this first thing in the morning.

Answer (score 0):

You could send the integers over as strings, then have logic on the server side to cast them to determine if they are numeric, and cast them to the correct type if they are.

```
// Server-side CLR object
class CoolObject
{
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Values { get; set; }
}

// Client-side JSON sent to the server
{
    TypeName: "MyType",
    Values: [
        "12",
        "asdf",
        "32.2"
    ]
}
```